# case when within case when as a calculation column

Tags: sql

I had massive support in the past from the forum and hope someone can help me with my query i.e.

I have case when within case when and want to return it as a column but somewhere there is an error coming as `''` error but I can not see it. Any help welcome.

thanks

```
CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING(a.DET_NOMINALDR,3,2) =’BS’ 
THEN 0 
ELSE a.DET_NOMINALDR 
END as NEW_DET_NOMINALDR
    WHEN SUBSTRING(a.DET_NOMINALCR,3,2) =’BS’
 then 0 
else a.DET_NOMINALCR 
end as NEW_DET_NOMINALCR
WHEN NEW_DET_NOMINALDR = 0
    THEN NEW_DET_NOMINALCR
    ELSE NEW_DET_NOMINALDR AS NOMINAL
END
```

Comment: Your parentheses don't balance.  That said, nested `case`s are rarely needed.  Usually you can just use on `case` with multiple `when` clauses.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write...

Answer (score 0):

you were missing closing parenthesis on your substrings

```
   select 
    (
    Case when ( 
    (Case when (substring(a.DET_NOMINALDR,3,2)) ='BS' then '' else a.DET_NOMINALDR end) ='') then 
    (Case when (substring(a.DET_NOMINALCR,3,2)) ='BS' then '' else a.DET_NOMINALCR end) 
    else (Case when (substring(a.DET_NOMINALDR,3,2)) ='BS' then '' else a.DET_NOMINALDR end) end) as Nominal
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfect, I can now progress with the rest. Not sure why I haven't seen it